# Beginner probability question: show that self confidence goes up after a confidence building event

Tags: probability

**The question**

An unconfident guy has a successful confidence building event (ie gets asked out on a date). Does his confidence go up?

**My attempt**

Let $A =$ percent belief in himself (percent confidence in himself)

Let $E =$ a successful confidence building experience

The guy is unconfident so let's say $P(A) = 0.01$

The question now is, $P(A|E) > P(A)$ ?

$$P(A|E) > P(A)$$

$$\frac{P(E|A)P(A)}{P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|A^c)P(A^c)} > P(A)$$

$$P(E|A) > P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|A^c)P(A^c)$$

$$ 1 > P(A) + \frac{P(E|A^c)P(A^c)}{P(E|A)}$$

$$ 1 - P(A) > \frac{P(E|A^c)P(A^c)}{P(E|A)}$$

$$ P(E|A) > P(E|A^c)$$

Therefore, his confidence will go up if the last equality above holds. However, I would say that the event of a succesful confidence building event is less likely if he is not confident than if he is confident.

That is I believe $ P(E|A) < P(E|A^c)$ if the initial confidence is low, ie $P(A)=.01$

Therefore, $P(A|E) < P(A)$ which implies his confidence level went down after being asked out. But of course that doesn't make sense because by definition $E$ is a confidence increasing event. My reasoning is messed up or maybe this is too soft of a problem. Can you help point out where I'm wrong?

**FYI**

I started thinking about this after seeing the following post on Reddit. The title of the Reddit post mentioned Bayesian reasoning which maybe it shouldn't have as the article doesn't mention it but it got me thinking. No need to click below if you don't want.

https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/comments/99ob4k/fake_it_until_you_make_it_is_common_advice_for/

Comment: Also since my reasoning above is wrong, if you could prove that confidence goes up "mathematically" using probabilities and conditioning then that would be great. Maybe that's not possible, maybe this is not a well formed question. Thanks for your help!